# Dart Null-Check subpattern? error in IntelliJIDEA

Tags: dart, intellij-idea

According to the official dart documentation (https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types) the following pattern should be valid:

```dart
String? maybeString = 'nullable with base type String';

switch (maybeString) {
  case var s?:
    break;
    // 's' has type non-nullable String here.
}
```

I am developing in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3 (Community Edition) with Dart 3.0.5 and I am getting the following error:

```
bin/dart_testproject.dart:7:16: Error: Expected an identifier, but got ':'.
Try inserting an identifier before ':'.
    case var a?:
```

I was on an older version of dart and IntelliJ before. Updated everything to the newest official releases but the error remains.

Comment: Have you updated your `pubspec.yaml` so the environment sdk are set to `"^3.0.0"`?

Comment: Great. I have posted an answer you can accept if you agree on the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode, this code works as I would expect:

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final secs = DateTime.now().second;
  final maybeString = secs.isOdd ? 'nullable with base type String' : null;
  switch (maybeString) {
    case final s?:
      print(s);
  }
}
```

`s` is correctly inferred as a non-null String.  So maybe this problem is unique to Jetbrains?  Have you tried it in Android Studio?

Comment: It also works fine in Intellij for me so I have the guess it is the `pubspec.yaml` that have not been updated.

Answer (score 0):

When using Dart, it is often not enough to just update the Dart SDK itself for getting new features. You also need to ensure the `pubspec.yaml` file specifies this version of Dart as a minimum requirement.

So for getting access to features introduced in Dart 3.0, we can do the following in the `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ^3.0.0
```

[(The `^` syntax makes it basically: `>=3.0.0 <4.0.0`)](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#version-constraints)

Reason being that Dart keeps track of which version a given feature got introduced and will prevent using the feature in case your project is specified to be compatible with Dart versions which does not have access to the feature. This makes it so you can, in general, just keep updating Dart SDK while still being able to write code for older version of Dart.